# How to get the latest value in the array or elements

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of list and I want to get the value based on latest date.

For example:

```
a = {
  "3456" :["031","a","10-09-1988","fff","xxx/xxx","032","b","20-10-1999","sss","yyy/yyyy"],
  "5323" :["031","a","10-10-1999","fff","xxx/xxx","032","b","20-10-1988","sss","yyy/yyyy"],
}
```

The above dictionary has 2 entries which each have 2 dates:

- 32456 -> 10-09-1988 and 20-10-1999 *(in this 20-10-1999 is latest so i need yyy/yyy value as ouptut)*
- 5323 -> 10-10-1999 and 20-10-1988 *(in this 10-10-1999 is latest so i need xxx/xxx value as ouptut)*

I tried this script below but it is not working as expected

```
lst = sorted(a , key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[2], "%Y-%m-%d"))

new_dict = {( item[4]): item for item in lst}
```

Expected output:

```
yyy/yyy
xxx/xxx
```

Comment: first try to get expected output by `for loop` and `if condition` then use advance method.

Comment: `yyy/yyy` or `xxx/xxx` are from list after two index of greater date value

Comment: It is the element of array you can see it here ["031","a","10-09-1988","fff","xxx/xxx",

Comment: @Kasramvd yyy/yyy or xxx/xxx is part of array element for example it is the 2 element after each date

Answer (score 0):

**By normal for loop and if condition**

1. Your date format is in `day-month-year` i.e `%d-%m-%Y` and you are check in `"%Y-%m-%d"` format.
2. Used simple if condition to compare two date values.

**Demo**

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> a
{'3456': ['031', 'a', '10-09-1988', 'fff', 'xxx/xxx', '032', 'b', '20-10-1999', 'sss', 'yyy/yyyy'], '5323': ['031', 'a', '10-10-1999', 'fff', 'xxx/xxx', '032', 'b', '20-10-1988', 'sss', 'yyy/yyyy']}
>>> final_result = []
>>> for key in a:
...    if datetime.strptime(a[key][2], "%d-%m-%Y") > datetime.strptime(a[key][7], "%d-%m-%Y"):
...        final_result.append(a[key][4])
...    else:
...        final_result.append(a[key][9])
... 
>>> final_result
['yyy/yyyy', 'xxx/xxx']
>>>
```

Comment: you have assume a[key][4] and a[key][9] but think the array will have more elements how could i automate it?

Comment: I given solution on hardcode value(input that u given). Now you can modify code according to ur input.

Answer (score 0):

First, when you use `sorted` on `a` you are getting a list of dictionaries *sorted keys*, because when you iterate over a dictionary you iterate over the keys. You then try to use `strptime` as a key function, but that won't work because you are indexing into the strings like `"3456"`, so `x[2]` is `5`. Finally, you try to make a `new_dict`, but I don't know what you are expecting, because dictionaries are inherently unordered.

If we can assume the form of your **list** values are *always the same*, then you don't want to sort the list values, really. Just use the following:

```
In [4]: def extract(x, ts="%d-%m-%Y"):
    ...:     if datetime.strptime(x[2], ts) > datetime.strptime(x[7], ts):
    ...:         return x[4]
    ...:     else:
    ...:         return x[9]
    ...:
```

Now you can use a loop or comprehension:

```
In [5]: [extract(lst) for lst in a.values()]
Out[5]: ['xxx/xxx', 'yyy/yyyy']
```

Note, you cannot guarantee the order of the above because *dictionaries are unordered*.

Unless you want to iterate over the sorted keys:

```
In [21]: [extract(a[k]) for k in sorted(a) ]
Out[21]: ['yyy/yyyy', 'xxx/xxx']
```

but it is unclear if that is what you want.

Comment: you have assume a[key][4] and a[key][9] but think the array will have more elements how could i automate it?

Comment: @Mounarajan it is a *list*, not an array. But do you have any control over this? This is a poor choice of data-structure. Your original post implied these lists would have this form, but what do you mean it could have more elements? Do you know *anything* about the structure of the list?

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you structure the data from the list first, and compare the date, and finally get the result.

```
from _datetime import datetime


data = {
    "3456": ["031", "a", "10-09-1988", "fff", "xxx/xxx", "032", "b", "20-10-1999", "sss", "yyy/yyyy"],
    "5323": ["031", "a", "10-10-1999", "fff", "xxx/xxx", "032", "b", "20-10-1988", "sss", "yyy/yyyy"]
}

obj_elements_num = 5
date_format = '%d-%m-%Y'


def string_to_date_object(date_string):
    return datetime.strptime(date_string, date_format)


for a_dict in data:
    tmp_date, tmp_value, tmp_len = "01-01-1970", "TMP", 0
    while tmp_len < len(data[a_dict]):
        _, _, cmp_date, _, value = data[a_dict][tmp_len:tmp_len+obj_elements_num]
        if string_to_date_object(cmp_date) > string_to_date_object(tmp_date):
            tmp_date, tmp_value = cmp_date, value
        tmp_len += obj_elements_num
    print(tmp_date, tmp_value)

----------------------------------------------------------------
20-10-1999 yyy/yyyy
10-10-1999 xxx/xxx
```